# Google Maps API v3: Disable the dropdown menu off the default MapTypeControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, customization

QUESTION:

Is it possible to hide the dropdown menu off the MapTypeControl?

(Nothing found in the Google Maps API v3 documentation).

DESCRIPTION:

 I'm using the default control with google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR style and i don't want to create a custom control.

MapTypeControl:

[image]

MapTypeControl with dropdown menu on mouseover:

[image]

Javascript:

```
var mapOptions = {
    ...
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    },
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MapTypeId.TERRAIN control looks to get added as a drop-down. Do you need it? If not, you can use the following code

```
var mapOptions = {
    ...
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        mapTypeIds: [
            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        ]
    },
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Comment: Worked. If you like to see street labels in the satellite view, you have to replace google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE with google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID.